# Daily admin email for products that went out of stock that day

Tags: admin, inventory, email

I am trying to set up a script to send out daily emails to my admin to let them know what went out of stock *that day only.*

It doesn't need to be anything fancy, perhaps even writing items to a text file as products go out of stock until the end of a day when that text files is sent out as an email and cleared for the next day?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer here? If yes, please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from the built-in RSS feed, there are two ways to actually send yourself an email - the actual answer to your actual question:

**Purchase an extension:**

I have no experience with this extension, but was mentioned on a StackOverflow:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/irzoo-lowstockreport-1278.html

**Do it yourself:**

Create an observer for `cataloginventory/stock_item` - on the save event. All models have save events provided by `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`. On save, it will call your observer, you can examine the stock level at that point.

```
<global>
    <events>
        <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>
            <observers>
                <mymodule_stock_item_save>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
                    <method>lowStockReport</method>
                </mymodule_stock_item_save>
            </observers>
        </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Observer.php:

```
<?php

class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function lowStockReport($observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $stockItem = $event->getItem();

        if($stockItem->getQty() < $stockItem->getNotifyStockQty()){

            //stock is lower than the notify amount, send email

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($stockItem->getProductId());

            $body = "{$product->getName()} :: {$product->getSku()} just Ran out of stock:\n\n";
            $body .= "Current Qty: {$stockItem->getQty()}\n";
            $body .= "Low Stock Date: {$stockItem->getLowStockDate()}\n";

            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
            $mail->setBodyHtml($body);
            $mail->setFrom('lowstock@yourwebsite.com', 'Low Stock Notifier');
            $mail->addTo('youremail@gmail.com', 'Your Name Here');
            $mail->setSubject('[Notice] An Item Has Gone Out of Stock');
            $mail->send();
        }
    }
}
```

This sends an email every time a stock item model is saved and the quantity on-hand is lower than the notify quantity set in Admin > Catalog > Manage Products.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The DIY route here is on the right track.  The OP asked for a single email per night though, so I would suggest a table with 'product_id', 'timestamp', and 'notified' columns.  When a product goes out of stock add an entry, when it comes back, remove the entry.  Nightly you send an email for all un-notified and set the flag.  That keeps you from notifying multiple times for each product, but you do get notification the next time the product goes out of stock.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after` event is not triggered on purchase, at least in recent Magento versions. See here for alternative solutions: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25207/detect-inventory-change

Comment: One minor change to the wonderful explanation of @philwinkle Instead of: $stockItem = $observer->getEvent() use: $stockItem = $observer->getEvent() –getItem()

Answer (score 1):

Old question, however I don't feel like it was ever really answered. I would add a and cronjob to the config.xml file in a custom module, figure out which products would need to be on the e-mail by building the collection (as below), then email the results.

```
    $date = strtotime('yesterday');

    $collection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('backorders', 0) 
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 0) 
    ->addFieldToFilter('manage_stock', 1) 
    ->addFieldToFilter('low_stock_date', array('date' => true, 'from' => date("Y-m-d", $date)))
    ->getAllIds();
```

Answer (score -1):

While not an Out of Stock alert, Magento ships with a low stock RSS feed which might suit your needs.

[image: Low Stock RSS Feed]

Comment: how can i get downloadable report, rss just see the report

Answer (score -1):

You could just use the native RSS feed for inventory - run a diff against the previous day's stock (ie. to find what changed only) - then fire off an email based on the result.

It would be a super simple ~10 line PHP script.

---

If you want something more sophisticated as a proper extension, then you'll need to add an observer to the `order_save` or stock index - to be able to capture then a value goes below 0 - and create a summary based on those values.

Comment: I do not have the experience unfortunately to build this but if you do, would you be interested in a fee for your services? My client would really benefit from it.