# Trying to create an observer that notifies when an item goes out of stock returning null

Tags: admin, event-observer, email, inventory

***SOLVED ON MY OWN**** 
Hi guys,

I just solved it using a debugger. It seems that getStockItem() was trying to get an object that doesn't exist that's why it was returning "null". The correct call was getItem(). This got me all the information I needed to know. Thank you for your help guys.

---

I have created a module in magento that will send an email when an item goes out of stock. I used this as a template : [Daily admin email for products that went out of stock that day](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/daily-admin-email-for-products-that-went-out-of-stock-that-day/3287#3287)

My issue, that  `if($stockItem->getQty() === $stockItem->getNotifyStockQty())`  is always to null... I am thinking that the event I am listening for in my config.xml file is the wrong event. The event in question: `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after`.

I get an email, but there is no data, it just sends me the strings written in the observer file `:: just Ran out of stock: Current Qty: Low Stock Date:`

What would be the right event to listen for?

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function lowStockReport($observer)
    {
        $stockItem = $observer->getEvent();
        if($stockItem->getQty() === $stockItem->getNotifyStockQty()){
            //stock is lower than the notify amount, send email
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($stockItem->getProductId());
            $body = "{$product->getName()} :: {$product->getSku()} just Ran out of stock:\n\n";
            $body .= "Current Qty: {$stockItem->getQty()}\n";
            $body .= "Low Stock Date: {$stockItem->getLowStockDate()}\n";
            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
            $mail->setBodyHtml($body);
            $mail->setFrom('lowstock@yourwebsite.com', 'Low Stock Notifier');
            $mail->addTo('youremail@gmail.com', 'Your Name Here');
            $mail->setSubject('[Notice] An Item Has Gone Out of Stock');
            $mail->send();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Could you please add more code from your observer?

Comment: If you solved your own questions - please add this as an answer and accept it. If any of the other provided answers got you on the right track feel free to accept one of those adding a comment what you had to do in addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problems is that `$stockItem` is event object.

Try to get stock item object from event

```
$stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getStockItem();
```

Comment: hi, I did this and i got this error "Call to a member function getQty() on a non-object"

Comment: Then run `var_dump($observer)` and investigate what is in the object.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the `_afterSave` method in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` that is triggered you can see that the current object is passed into the event dispatcher as `'object'`: `Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_after', array('object'=>$this));`.

This means you can get that object via `$observer->getEvent()->getObject()` in your own observer.