# Hiding items in a bundle?

Tags: bundled-product

I have a bundle of items with fixed quantities and a fixed price.

If I the items are "A, B, C, D, and E"...

I want to show instead "A, B, Group 1, and E".  Basically, hide products C and D.

The reason I have to hide some of the items is to fulfill a very specific business case where users aren't allowed to know what items are in Group 1.

The only approach I can think of so far is to use php to adjust the template code, but after a bit of thinking I realized I might have to make template changes for the product page, cart display, checkout, invoices, etc., and it sounds kind of messy.

If there's a simpler way to think about this or implement, I'd much appreciate any thoughts and suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you need it like this, you need to change the display in lots of places (be it with custom templates or observers).

But it sounds like you only need "C" and "D" for stock keeping purposes. In this case a simpler solution would be to create an actual product "Group 1" and add it to the bundle. Then write an observer for stock changes of this product, which adjusts the stock of the real products "C" and "D" accordingly.

Further reading: [Detect inventory change](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/25207/243)