# Can't Update Stock Quantity on Simple Product based Configurable Product in Magento Admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, adminhtml, inventory

- Our request is to have quantities on configurable products, based on total quantity of simple associated products. With this d we will be able to filter configurable products by quantity admin panel.
- Can't Update Stock Quantity on Simple Product based Configurable Product in Magento Admin panel

  please check screen short and thanks advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25207/detect-inventory-change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app/etc/modules/Test_Configqty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Test_Configqty>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Test_Configqty>
  </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Test/Configqty/etc/config,xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Test_Configqty>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Test_Configqty>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
        <configqty>
            <class>Test_Configqty_Helper</class>
        </configqty>
        <catalogInventory>
            <rewrite>
                <data>Test_Configqty_Helper_Cataloginventorydata</data>
            </rewrite>
        </catalogInventory>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <configqty>
        <class>Test_Configqty_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>configqty_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </configqty>
    </models>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_prepare_save> 
            <observers>
              <catalog_product_prepare_save_handler> 
                <type>singleton</type> 
                <class>configqty/observer</class> 
                <method>configqty</method> 
                <args></args> 
              </catalog_product_prepare_save_handler>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_prepare_save>

        <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <configqty_stockupdate>
                    <class>configqty/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogInventorySave</method>
                </configqty_stockupdate>
            </observers>
        </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>

        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
            <observers>
                <configqty_stockupdate>
                    <class>configqty/observer</class>
                    <method>subtractQuoteInventory</method>
                </configqty_stockupdate>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>

        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure>
            <observers>
                <configqty_stockupdate>
                    <class>configqty/observer</class>
                    <method>revertQuoteInventory</method>
                </configqty_stockupdate>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure>

        <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
            <observers>
                <configqty_stockupdate>
                    <class>configqty/observer</class>
                    <method>refundOrderInventory</method>
                </configqty_stockupdate>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>

    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Test/Configqty/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Test_Configqty_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

> app/code/local/Test/Configqty/Helper/Cataloginventorydata.php

```
<?php
class Test_Configqty_Helper_Cataloginventorydata extends Mage_CatalogInventory_Helper_Data
{
    public function getIsQtyTypeIds($filter = null)
    {
        if (null === self::$_isQtyTypeIds) {
            self::$_isQtyTypeIds = array();
            $productTypesXml = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/catalog/product/type');
            foreach ($productTypesXml->children() as $typeId => $configXml) {
                self::$_isQtyTypeIds[$typeId] = (bool)$configXml->is_qty;
                if($typeId == "configurable"){
                    self::$_isQtyTypeIds[$typeId] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (null === $filter) {
            return self::$_isQtyTypeIds;
        }
        $result = self::$_isQtyTypeIds;
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            if ($value !== $filter) {
                unset($result[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

> app/code/local/Test/Configqty/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Test_Configqty_Model_Observer
{
    public function configqty(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        $productId = $product->getId();

        if($product->getTypeID() == "configurable") {
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);

            $p_qty = 0;

            $configurable_products_data = $product->getData('configurable_products_data');

            $childProducts = array_keys($configurable_products_data);

            foreach($childProducts as $child) {
                $childStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($child);

                $p_qty += $childStockItem->getQty();
            }

            $stockItem->setQty($p_qty);
            $stockItem->setIsInStock((int)($p_qty > 0));

            $product->setData('stock_item', $stockItem);
        }
    }


    public function catalogInventorySave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {   
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $_item = $event->getItem();

        if ((int)$_item->getData('qty') != (int)$_item->getOrigData('qty')) {

            $product_id = $_item->getProductId();
            $qty = $_item->getQty();

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

            if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple') {
                $parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                      ->getParentIdsByChild($product_id);
                //var_dump($parentIds);

                foreach($parentIds as $parentId) {
                    //$parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentId);

                    $p_qty = 0;
                    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getChildrenIds($parentId);

                    //var_dump($childProducts);
                    foreach($childProducts[0] as $child) {
                        $childStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($child);

                        $p_qty += $childStockItem->getQty();
                    }

                    $parentStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($parentId);
                    $parentStockItem->setQty($p_qty);
                    $parentStockItem->setIsInStock((int)($p_qty > 0));
                    $parentStockItem->save();
                }
            }
            //exit;
            /* $params['qty'] = 100;
            $params['qty_change'] = $_item->getQty() - $_item->getOrigData('qty'); */

            /* $qty = 100;
            $_item->setQty($qty);
            $_item->setIsInStock((int)($qty > 0));
            $_item->save(); */
        }

    }
    public function subtractQuoteInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {

            $product_id = $item->getProductId();
            $qty = $item->getQty();

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);


            if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple') {
                $parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                      ->getParentIdsByChild($product_id);
                //var_dump($parentIds);

                foreach($parentIds as $parentId) {
                    //$parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentId);

                    $p_qty = 0;
                    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getChildrenIds($parentId);

                    //var_dump($childProducts);
                    foreach($childProducts[0] as $child) {
                        $childStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($child);

                        $p_qty += $childStockItem->getQty();
                    }

                    $parentStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($parentId);
                    $parentStockItem->setQty($p_qty);
                    $parentStockItem->setIsInStock((int)($p_qty > 0));
                    $parentStockItem->save();

                    //Mage::log("p_qty: ".$p_qty. "  product_id".$product_id, null, 'mylogfile.log');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public function revertQuoteInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {

            $product_id = $item->getProductId();
            $qty = $item->getQty();

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);


            if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple') {
                $parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                      ->getParentIdsByChild($product_id);
                //var_dump($parentIds);

                foreach($parentIds as $parentId) {
                    //$parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentId);

                    $p_qty = 0;
                    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getChildrenIds($parentId);

                    //var_dump($childProducts);
                    foreach($childProducts[0] as $child) {
                        $childStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($child);

                        $p_qty += $childStockItem->getQty();
                    }

                    $parentStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($parentId);
                    $parentStockItem->setQty($p_qty);
                    $parentStockItem->setIsInStock((int)($p_qty > 0));
                    $parentStockItem->save();

                    //Mage::log("p_qty: ".$p_qty. "  product_id".$product_id, null, 'mylogfile.log');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public function refundOrderInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $creditmemo = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo();
        foreach ($creditmemo->getAllItems() as $item) {

            $product_id = $item->getProductId();
            $qty = $item->getQty();

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);


            if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple') {
                $parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                      ->getParentIdsByChild($product_id);
                //var_dump($parentIds);

                foreach($parentIds as $parentId) {
                    //$parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentId);

                    $p_qty = 0;
                    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getChildrenIds($parentId);

                    //var_dump($childProducts);
                    foreach($childProducts[0] as $child) {
                        $childStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($child);

                        $p_qty += $childStockItem->getQty();
                    }

                    $parentStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($parentId);
                    $parentStockItem->setQty($p_qty);
                    $parentStockItem->setIsInStock((int)($p_qty > 0));
                    $parentStockItem->save();

                    //Mage::log("p_qty: ".$p_qty. "  product_id".$product_id, null, 'mylogfile.log');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```