# Update Product Attribute based on Stock Levels [Magento 1.9]

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, stock

I am trying to have two out of my Product Attributes updated once the Stock Level reaches 0, or goes above 0.

Would this be possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at observers. Although stock is a bit tricky. You probably want to add your own event and then catch it in an observer.  You should then be able to update products with the desired attribute values based on stock number.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/83178/70343

Comment: What I was thinking..there's a bit somewhere where when the stock level reaches 0 the text on the "Order now" button is being changed to "Back-Order". If I could just add statement to change the attributes there. What would you say ?